# can SimpleXMLRPCServer listen on multiple addresses?

Tags: python, simplexmlrpcserver

I have two IPs mapping to the machine, and I was wondering how I can have one python xmlrpc server listening on both IPs (same port), like you could do with Apache.

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "" as the host:

```
s = SimpleXMLRPCServer.SimpleXMLRPCServer(("", 8000))
```

Comment: You see, I would have spent hours trying to figure this out, or coming up with a a harder way to go about it. I thank you sir.